# How to resize background images according to their resolution in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, pictures, desktop-customization

Specifically, I wonder how to make background image display automatically to **fit** screen when its resolution is larger than the screen and to **center** in the screen when its resolution is smaller than the screen?

I've found John's Background Switcher supports this setting but doesn't do it well. And Is it possible without using external software?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the desktop and select "Personalize"

Click on the desktop background tile at the bottom of the dialog. On this page at the bottom, click on the drop-down labeled Picture position and change to your liking. You most likely want to use stretch for a smaller image or fit for a larger one.